# Can't gem install with containerized and built-from-source ruby 2.5.1

Tags: ruby, docker, ruby-2.5

I can't seem to get gem working within a Docker container that's got a ruby 2.5.1 built from source. This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openssl
RUN apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev

#Install ruby
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y gcc
RUN wget https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.5/ruby-2.5.1.tar.gz
RUN tar -xf ruby-2.5.1.tar.gz
RUN apt-get install make
RUN cd ruby-2.5.1 && ./configure && make && make install
```

If I try to issue the command `gem install bundler` from within a container derived from the above `Dockerfile`, I get:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::Exception)
Unable to require openssl, install OpenSSL and rebuild Ruby (preferred) or use non-HTTPS sources
```

How could I fix this error?

- I've tried adding a `--with-openssl-dir=$(which openssl)` to the `./configure` instruction, but it was to no avail.
- If I don't issue the `apt-get install -y zlib1g-dev` command, the installation still succeeds, but I get an error saying that the `zlib` package is missing.

Comment: You presumably need OpenSSL header files, but it's probably much easier to just use the prebuilt [ruby:2.5.1](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/) image and not worry about it.

Comment: @DavidMaze i want to have ubuntu as my container's OS. AFAIK, the prebuilt ruby images ship with debian.